# Соловей — этимология

Tags: этимология

Интересно, слово "соловей" русское? С одной стороны, "соло" — вроде как корень не русский, означающий сольное пение. С другой стороны, может быть, тут совершенно другое происхождение.
Вообще, происхождение названий животных очень интересны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

М. Фасмер объясняет этимологию слова так: "Солове́й род. п. -вья́, укр. соловíй, солове́й, блр. солове́йка, др.-русск. соловии, русск.-цслав. славии ἀηδών, болг. сла́вей, сербохорв. сла̀ву̑j, род. п. славу́jа, также сла̑вjа ж., сла̑вља, сла̑вjе, словен. slávǝc, род. п. slávca, чеш. slavík, слвц. slávik, польск. sɫowik, в.-луж. syɫobik, soɫobik, н.-луж. syɫojik, syɫojk, полаб. salǘöj. Праслав. *solvijь, производное от* solvъ "желтовато-серый"; см. солово́й; ср. Остхоф, Раrеrgа 96; Лёвенталь, Farbenbez. 16; Младенов 588; Брюкнер 501. Родственно др.-прусск. salowis "соловей", которое относится к слав. *solvijь, как др.-русск. жеравль – к лит. gérvė "журавль"; см. Эндзелин, RS 11, 37. Что касается знач., то ср. греч. χλωρηὶς ἀηδών, ξουθη ἀηδών; см. Шрадер–Неринг 2, 398. Нет основания отделять солово́й от этого слова и сближать его с лит. šalvas, šalvìs "хариус", вопреки Зубатому (AfslPh 16, 413 и сл.), Шпехту (122), Булаховскому (ОЛЯ 7, 110), Буге (KS I, 289), или сравнивать с д.-в.-н. swalawa "ласточка", др.-исл. svala – то же, англос. swealwe, вопреки Сольмсену (AfslPh 24, 575 и сл.), Торбьёрнссону (I, 26), Хольтхаузену (Awn. Wb. 290). Весьма сомнительно родство с греч. κολοιός "галка, Corvus monedula", вопреки Бецценбергеру (ВВ 27, 169). Распространено также собств. Солове́й, фам. Соловьёв, чеш. Slavík, польск. Sɫowik; см. Соболевский, ЖСт. I, 2, 98. Вместе с тем Солове́й Будими́рович – имя заморского богатыря, сватающего дочь Владимира (в былинах), может быть, также иноязычного происхождения. Согласно Хайнцелю (у Ягича, AfslPh 12, 602), здесь отражено распространенное имя собств. др.-исл. So<lvi, др.-шв. Salve (Линд, Norsk-isl. Dорnаmn I, 1020). Знаменитого персонажа русск. народн. творчества – Соловья-разбойника О. Миллер (см. Ягич, там же, I, 125) пытался отождествить с могучим мордвином (XVII в.) близ Нижнего Новгорода. Ср. в связи с этим морд. salams "красть", salitśa "вор", фин. sala "тайное", мар. šоlо "вор", венг. tolvaj – то же, манси tolmaχ "вор", ю.-ханты totmaχ – то же (об этих словах – без русск. – см. Шимоньи, Diе ungar. Sрrасhе 23; Паасонен, Diе fi-ugr. s-Laute 48 и сл.; Мordw. Chrest. 120). Во всяком случае, у имени собств. Солове́й нет ничего общего с Соломон, вопреки Ягичу (AfslPh)"

Comment: Интересно, так что все-таки первично: имя собственное или название птицы?

Comment: Я не думаю, что открою Америку, если скажу, что первично имя нарицательное.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, у меня не поместился ответ в комментарий, сделал его ответом темы.

Answer (score 1):

Fuchoin Kazuki, Вопрос насчет первичности не так прост. Смотря что и как понимать.

По поводу исходного (древнего) имени у Фасмера сказано вполне однозначно. Поскольку имя собственное и имя нарицательное имеют разное происхождение и не оказали прямого влияния друг на друга, то и вопрос о первичности не стоит. Я не вижу причин оспаривать фасмеровскую версию происхождения имени собственного (в отличие от фамилии, см. ниже), таким образом с какой-то уверенностью можно говорить только от том, что имя нарицательное появилось раньше, но не оно послужило основой для имени собственного. 
И, конечно же, верно и обратное: соловья-птицу  явно назвали не по имени собственному, а по масти. 
**//----**
В то же время нельзя не учитывать, что имя как-то могло связываться и c птицей. Соловей-разбойник, например, обладал особыми способностями насчет посвистеть (сразу вспоминается свита Воланда), в более поздний период Соловьем могли прозвать говоруна, краснобая.

Тем более не все так просто с фамилией. По Фасмеру получается, что фамилия - от имени собственного, которое изначально не связано с нарицательным. Боюсь, это не так. Вернее всего - от произвища, как и большинство русских фамилий. Происхождение же прозвищ вполне может быть связано как раз с птицей.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, соловей - от скандинавского слова "сильный" - сольвейг. Окраска как-то не вяжется с птичкой - тогда бы вОрона называли "черный", а лиса была была бы просто "рыжовка"? и т.д.
Сольвейг=соловей, потому что "бьёт"  так сильно - за километр услышишь его голосок, ни она птица с этой крошечкой не сравнится.

Comment: А какие-нибудь более весомые аргументы, чем "мне кажется" у этой версии есть?